# How can I diagnose an Xcode Code Signing failure?

Tags: xcode, code-signing

With Xcode 10.2 I'm getting a Code Signing failure of 
`resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code`
but I don't how to find which particular element of the massive project is causing the problem.

This, by the way, was not occurring with Xcode 10.1. Back then I did find that some of my .png images contained color profiles which were removed and stopped a code signing failure there.

The current failure occurred after bringing the code unchanged from under 10.1 where no failure happens. And it does not happen either when I take the code as modified under 10.2 back to 10.1. So this is making me crazy!

Now, I can't even find Apple documentation to help me find what to fix!  Any suggestions will be gratefully processed. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that these are `.DS_Store` files. You won't see them in the finder but you should be able to see them from the terminal. `cd` to Xcode's output folder and do `find . -name .DS_Store`.

Comment: Thanks @Rudedog, but I found no DS_Store files, nor any  ._ resource fork files.

Comment: I discovered the problem. See my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I examined (again) the dense paragraph above the code signing error message. The main thing it contained was a path to my app bundle. So I thought something extraneous might be within the bundle.

I went to the Products folder in the project navigator panel in Xcode and right-clicked my app, then selected Show in Finder, then in the Finder I right-clicked the app and selected Show Package Contents, then expanded the Contents directory and then the Resources directory which is the most likely place to find detritus.

Sure enough, there was a .png image file which I had rejected for use while experimenting with the app. I had commented out `//` the code lines referring to it, but had not deleted that image file from among the Supporting Files in the Xcode navigation panel.

I did delete it and re-built the app. *Voila*, no more code signing fault!

Thanks, guys, for your kind attention to this question, and all the questions people ask.